# Cannot ssh to raspberry pi through hostname after upgrading to Jessie

Tags: linux, ssh, raspberry-pi

For a long time, as long as I connect my Mac and RP directly using a single cable (with or without any other devices like monitor or keyboards connected), I can ssh to my RP using command

```
ssh pi@raspberrypi.local
```

Yesterday, I upgraded to Jessie, then strange thing happens:

- If the monitor is connected (through HDMI) when booting the RP

  - If my mac is connected to a Wifi, the ssh will FAIL! However, if I immediately re-ssh again, it will succeed!
  - If my mac is not connected to other networks, the ssh will succeed.
- If the monitor is not connected when booting, I can NOT ssh through hostname.
- In both case the RP is not connected to any wifi or other networks.

Neither before of after upgrading have I modified any system configuration.

Could anyone help? Particularly, I am wondering how does connecting a monitor through HDMI affect ssh connection?!

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking this on [su] or maybe [unix.se].

Answer (score 0):

You could ssh manually to the pi's local ip address instead. You can view its ip in your router settings when it's connected then run ssh pi@xxx.xxx.xxx. Hope this helps